# How do I remove a string of text between <a and </a> using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, html-parsing

I have been tasked with creating a script that pulls the toner levels from the printers in my orginization and pushes them out in a .csv format for excel reporting.  unfortunatially, when I add the printer heading, I am unable to remove the:

```
< a href="h_product=Q7493A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_tool=prodhomes" onclick="target = new Date().valueOf().toString(); if (window.open) window.open('h_product=Q7493A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_tool=prodhomes',target,'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes'); return false;" id="lnkOtherLink2">Product Support</a>
```

and the

```
< a href="http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Navh_product=CB480A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_page=hpcom&amp;hpagetype=s-001&amp;h_client=s-a-e001-1" onclick="target = new Date().valueOf().toString(); if (window.open) window.open('http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Navh_product=CB480A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_page=hpcom&amp;hpagetype=s-001&amp;h_client=s-a-e001-1',target,'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes'); return false;" id="lnkOtherLink2">Product Support</a>
```

Is there a way to remove the "< a" and the /a> and the data between them using a powershell command?  (spaces added and < removed so the code would appear.

A simple replace function will not work because of the special characters, and it seems rather messy to remove specific blocks of text.  since all of the blocks in question start and end with the "a" function, i figure that there has to be a way to do this. Conversly, there may be a way to avoid this all together.

Comment: Did you know that you can use `SNMP` for this kind of queries?

Comment: Why can't you use `-replace` ? `$string -replace "< a(.*)/a>"` works fine for me, where `$string` is the second sample (I added "</a>" at the end).

Comment: What do you mean by 'data between them' - do you want to be left with 'Product Support'?

Comment: By .cvs format you probably meant .CSV (comma-separated values). However, it is not clear what you want to filter, and which part you would like to drop. Please include sample output.

Comment: Printer1, 

<a href="h_product=Q7493A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_tool=prodhomes" onclick="target = new Date().valueOf().toString(); if (window.open) window.open('h_product=Q7493A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_tool=prodhomes',target,'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes'); return false;" id="lnkOtherLink2">Product Support</a>

Black Cartridge,91%,

Cyan Cartridge,59%,

Magenta Cartridge,44%,

Yellow Cartridge,24%,

Image Transfer Kit,75%,

Image Fuser Kit,21%,

Comment: printer2, 

<a href="http://12345.www2.hp.com/apps/Navh_product=CB480A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_page=hpcom&amp;hpagetype=s-001&amp;h_client=s-a-e001-1" onclick="target = new Date().valueOf().toString(); if (window.open) window.open('http://12345.www2.hp.com/apps/Navh_product=CB480A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_page=hpcom&amp;hpagetype=s-001&amp;h_client=s-a-e001-1',target,'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes'); return false;" id="lnkOtherLink2">Product Support</a>

<toner levels>

Comment: I want to remove the html text, all i want left is:

Printer1, 



Black Cartridge,91%,

Cyan Cartridge,59%,

Magenta Cartridge,44%,

Yellow Cartridge,24%,

Image Transfer Kit,75%,

Image Fuser Kit,21%,



printer2, 



Black Cartridge,91%,

Cyan Cartridge,59%,

Magenta Cartridge,44%,

Yellow Cartridge,24%,

Image Transfer Kit,75%,

Image Fuser Kit,21%,

Answer (score 0):

According to your recent comments, `-replace "<a(.*?)</a>"` should do the trick.

Here is sample usage:

```
$tmp = @'
Printer1, <a href="h_product=Q7493A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_tool=prodhomes" onclick="target = new Date().valueOf().toString(); if (window.open) window.open('h_product=Q7493A&amp;h_lang=en&amp;h_cc=us&amp;h_tool=prodhomes',ta‌​rget,'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,toolbar=yes,status=ye‌​s'); return false;" id="lnkOtherLink2">Product Support</a> Black Cartridge,91%, Cyan Cartridge,59%, Magenta Cartridge,44%, Yellow Cartridge,24%, Image Transfer Kit,75%, Image Fuser Kit,21%,
'@

$tmp -replace "<a(.*?)</a>", ""
```

Notice regex greedy qualifier (`?`), without it you would have captured everything starting from the beginning of your first `<a>` tag to the end of your last one, which may not be what you want (depending on full page contents).

With that said, I can't believe HP printers do not have an API to check toner levels in a proper way.

Comment: Aparantly I had the Syntax all wrong, I was missing the "." and the "?"  It worked awesome, thank you verry much

Comment: @user2041104: I'm glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer accordingly.